# Delete File from Firebase Storage by NodeJs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to delete a file from my firebase storage by a nodeJs script. I checked the official documentation:

```
 // Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your app's config object
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket-url>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
  var storage = firebase.storage();
```

For firebase im using the npm firebase.

I get the following error: firebase storage is not a function.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. Using firebase on server site differs to client site. I switched to firebase-admin --> see in doc:

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/automatically-delete-your-firebase-storage-files-from-firestore-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-36542c39ba0d

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to production mode, it is best practice to only import the packages you require which, I suspect, is what you are missing. The follow code snippet should do the trick.

```
// IMPORT
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require("firebase/storage");

// INIT
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(yourConfig);
const storage = firebaseApp.storage();
```